# Add Handling page creation events in your SPFx application customizer

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I have the following inside my application customizer SPFX extension, the code is responsible to load custom CSS inside the home page `https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/customeroperations/sitepages/dashboard.aspx`:-

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';

import * as strings from 'HelloWorldApplicationCustomizerStrings';

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer';

/**
 * If your command set uses the ClientSideComponentProperties JSON input,
 * it will be deserialized into the BaseExtension.properties object.
 * You can define an interface to describe it.
 */
export interface IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties {
  // This is an example; replace with your own property
  cssurl: string;
  scripturl: string;
}

/** A Custom Action which can be run during execution of a Client Side Application */
export default class HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

    @override

    public onInit(): Promise<void> {
      Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);
  
      const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;
      this.context.application.navigatedEvent.add(this ,()=>{
      const scriptUrl: string = this.properties.scripturl;

      const url = window.location.href;
      if (cssUrl && 
      (url.toLowerCase()=="https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/customeroperations/sitepages/dashboard.aspx"
      ||
      url.toLowerCase()== "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/customeroperations"
      ) )
      {
          // inject the style sheet
          const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
          let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
          customStyle.href = cssUrl;
          customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
          customStyle.type = "text/css";

          const head2: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
          
          head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
          head2.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300">');

          

      }
      else
      {
        const links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
        for(let i=0; i < links.length;i++ )
        {


          if(links[i].href.indexOf(cssUrl)>-1){
          links[i].remove();
          }

        }


      }
    });
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

now the code is working well, except when I create a new page the custom CSS will be applied to the new blank page although it is not the home page. After some reading I realized that my above code will not work on new page creation, where I found this link @ https://www.eliostruyf.com/handling-page-creation-events-spfx-application-customizer to how to handle page creation navigation... but I am not sure how I need to modify my above code to handle the page creation and not load the custom CSS, since the new page url != the url of the home page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to add Elio's code to your Application Customizer class. Add both the `bindToHistory` and `handleNewPageReload` methods to your class, and call `bindToHistory` inside `onInit`, just after the `Log` call.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but can you provide a general code to how to do the merge between my code and Elio's code?

Comment: are you able to advice more on this ?